# How to provide dynamic condtion to select/unselect a rowSelection checkbox in ag-grid-react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ag-grid-react

I'm trying to select same client based rows based on first selected row(clientName) in the grid not sure how we can achieve this.

```
<Grid
    onGridReady={onGridReady}
    rowData={dataset}
    floatingFilter
    sideBar={GRID_SIDE_BAR}
    onSelectionChanged={getSelectedRowData}
    licenseKey={'test'}
    enableSelect={true}
    rowSelection={'multiple'}
    getRowId={getRowNodeId}
    columnDefs={columnDefs}
    defaultColDef={defaultColDef}
    cacheQuickFilter={true}
/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After read the document I found the solution to using **onSelectionChanged** to achieved the same in the following way.

```
const [ clientName, setClientName ] = useState('')

const onGridReady = useCallback(params => {
    setGridParams(params)
}, [])

const getRowNodeId = useCallback(params => params.data.request_id, [])

const getSelectedRowData = useCallback(gridParams => {
        const selectedData = gridParams.api.getSelectedRows()

        if (selectedData.length === 1) {
            setClientName(selectedData.at(0).Clientid)
        }
        gridParams.api.forEachNode(node => {
            if (node.data && (node.data.Clientid === clientName || selectedData.length === 1) && selectedData.some(d => d.request_id === node.data.request_id)) {
                node.setSelected(true)
            } else {
                node.setSelected(false)
            }
        })

        return selectedData
    }, [ clientName ])
```